# Why can't IntelliJ find my class during runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

We have this project setup for eclipse that I'm now trying to import into IntelliJ.
I've tried using the eclipse import in IntelliJ but that fails, I suspect it's because the person who set up the project decided there shouldn't be a src-folder and instead named it after our course, tddc17...

The structure looks like this:

```
- project
  - lib (contains two jars)
  - tddc17
    - MyVacuumAgent.java
```

Now I've set up the jars as modules in IntelliJ and when I configure the run I can find the entry point so that's all good. The project also builds as it should but the problem is when I try to run it.
In one of the jars it tries to find "tddc17.MyVacuumAgent.java" which it then can't find.

I can't edit the jar so I can't change that, so what I need is a way to set it up so that it can be found. When building there's an out directory created with the structure:

```
- out
  - production
    - lab1 (name of the project in IntelliJ)
```

Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.

since it looked for tddc17.MyVacuumAgent.java it was expecting that to be part of a package. Which it wasn't. So I added `package tddc17` at the top of the file. THis gave me an error but using alt + enter to let IntelliJ fix it created yet another tddc17 folder inside the existing one and now it all works.

Comment: And this is why you should look into learning Maven when you get a bit further.  It explicitly says where sources are located in your project.